# Java Swing Key Handlers sporadically not working

Tags: java, swing, key-bindings

I am developing a Java Swing based video game.  I am having a problem with detecting keystrokes- the 'A' (move left) and 'D' keys (move right), where it almost seems they are not firing (but happens rarely).  Almost as if they have become unregistered.  Now, I have setup log files to capture the keyboard events, and again one of the keyHandlers at some point does not fire.  Now when this does happen, **if I click into the main screen** of the game with my mouse, the keyHandler that somehow got lost seems to work again.  Almost as if the "Focus" was inadvertantly transferred to some other widget in the game.

Here is the code to setup the Action Maps:

```
    topStatusPanel.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("pressed A"),
            "aCharKeyPressed");
    topStatusPanel.getActionMap().put("aCharKeyPressed", aKeyActionPressed);


    topStatusPanel.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("released A"), 
            "aCharKeyReleased");
    topStatusPanel.getActionMap().put("aCharKeyReleased", aKeyActionReleased);



    topStatusPanel.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("pressed D"), 
            "dCharKeyPressed");
    topStatusPanel.getActionMap().put("dCharKeyPressed", dKeyActionPressed);

    topStatusPanel.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("released D"), 
            "dCharKeyReleased");
    topStatusPanel.getActionMap().put("dCharKeyReleased", dKeyActionReleased);

    MoveSubLeftActionStart aKeyActionPressed= new MoveSubLeftActionStart();
    MoveSubLeftActionStop aKeyActionReleased= new MoveSubLeftActionStop();
    MoveSubRightActionStart dKeyActionPressed= newMoveSubRightActionStart();
    MoveSubRightActionStop dKeyActionReleased= new MoveSubRightActionStop();
```

Would really appreciate any ideas on this.  Is there a way to force focus to a specific widget?- would I then for every other widget in the game have to set it to "unfocusable?"  Could this be the issue?  Appreciate any help here.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: please read my comment in the answer by Jochen Bedersdorfer

Answer (score 0):

Here's an in-depth treatment on focus management and keyboard event handling.
If your JPanel contains other components, they might get the focus and not propagate the key events up the component chain.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/doc-files/FocusSpec.html#RequestingFocus

Comment: Focus is settable parameter in KeyBindings, this declaration missing in OPs code, maybe thats reason for

Comment: @mKorbel - I tried your suggestion, and used the parameter:WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT for the getInputMap call.  It didn't work - I am still having the same issues of sporadically losing keyboard events.  And for some reason, only occurs when the object I am moving is at either the far left or far right of screen, and winds up getting stuck there.  I do have the keybindings bound to the topStatusPanel of the game.  Wondering if maybe should try binding maybe to the jFrame itself or some root level panel.  Would really like to figure out what is going on here.

Comment: @user1104028 no idea without an SSCCE / MCVE, short, runnable, compilable with hardcoded value for GUI in local variables, there is limitations for more than two modifiers are pressed in the same time, I'm missing another ...